# How to change to in-memory stateStore instead of RocksDB in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In order to compare the performences of a Spring Cloud Stream application (with Kafka) using RocksDB or in-memory, I would like to change RocksDB to in-memory. Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution for that. I have found a solution for the DSL API and for the Processor API (https://simplydistributed.wordpress.com/2017/03/21/kafka-streams-state-stores/), but I'm not sure if it is applicable for the kafka-streams binder. Could someone help me in this issue?

Best regards
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams binder does not interact with RocksDB directly for any state store operations. It doesn't even know that it is communicating to RocksDB. All communication occurs through the Kafka Streams API and abstractions. Therefore, you can use custom state stores with Kafka Streams as suggested by the docs and the binder will continue to work. See if it works and please let us know if you find any issues.

Comment: I was about to say the same. You could get a `KStream` and use the DSL API like it's used in the the article you mentioned to have complete control of your streaming operations.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out!

Comment: One more question: On the inbound I'm using a `KTable<..., ...>`. In my _application.yml_ I have defined:

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.inputTable.consumer.materializedAs: tableStore`

So a store exists already, but I still have no idea how to change the properties in order to choose (persitant / in-memory). What would be the right approach for that?